# myether wallet not flashing my token after the confirmation

Tags: myetherwallet

I have just Transfered My Premine token to my Myetherwallet. The transcation show on etherscam confirmed but myether is not flashing or showing my token. Does myetherwallet usually takes time to show your transferred token?

Comment: Some new tokens are not displayed in MEW but you can add them as a custom token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "click load" token beside the proper token. Or if you do not see the token on your interface, you're going to have to add it.

https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/send/adding-new-token-and-sending-custom-tokens.html